# Sequence contains no elements when trying to save the value property of dropdownlist to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genres)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genres, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "id", "name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

above is my view

```
public class GigFormViewModel
{
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int Genre { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my ViewModel

```
    public class Gig
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser artisrt { get; set; }

    public DateTime  dateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Genre genre { get; set; }
}
```

model

```
 public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var artistId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var artist = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == artistId);
        var genre = _context.genres.Single(g => g.id == viewModel.Genre);

        var gig = new Gig()
        {
            artisrt = artist,
            dateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}, {1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time)),
            genre = genre,
            venue = viewModel.Venue
        };


        _context.gigs.Add(gig);
        _context.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

and above is the controller and the exception is generating from where I am calling the genres.Single()

I have tried using SingleOrDefault() instead of Single() but in that case it is trying to save a null value in the database and the database does not allow nulls.

Edit: value of viewModel.Genre is 0 when I debug it.

Comment: In the database you don't have a user with id equal to the artistId.

Comment: You need to debug and find out what the value of viewModel.Genre is, and why it doesn't appear in your database.

Comment: value of viewModel.Genre is 0 when I debug it.

Comment: I think `DropDownListFor(m => m.Genres` should be `DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre` (you want to bind the `Genre` property, not `Genres` list)

Comment: Remove the `s` from `Genres` in `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genres`. It needs to be `Genre`. MVC is creating the dropdownlist for `Genres` so `Genre` will always have zero in it. Your dB most likely has no genre with ID 0 so it is throwing exception . what you want to use is `Genre`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, 
                        new SelectList(Model.Genres, "id", "name"), "", 
                        new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Where:

```
m => m.Genre
```

is the property where the result value will be stored (you are currently using the collection m => m.Genres instead of m.Genre)

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Np! Don't forget to upvote the answer too if it solved the issue!